# GIMP has vanished

Tags: installation, gimp

I'm a very new ubuntu user. I had someone install everything for me, including GIMP but since my last update it has simply vanished.

I have found some help on the subject but all tell me to install packages and I don't know how to do that.

Whenever I try to run any of these commands I get some response like this:

```
N: Ignoring file 'matthaeus123-mrw-gimp-svn-oneiric.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

When I type GIMP into Terminal, I get:

```
The program 'gimp' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

So I try the `apt-get` and this is what comes after:

```
E: Invalid operation gimp
```

Should I reinstall the whole system? Anyone can help please? :(

**UPDATE**

Ok I have deleted the file (yay!). I got the following errors:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources                              
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources                              
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
```

and also

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ripps818/wacom/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ripps818/wacom/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Then when I try to run apt-get on GIMP I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgegl-0.0-0 (>= 0.1.3-2) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.30.0-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What happens if you type `gimp` in a terminal? (add the answer to this into your question ;) )

Comment: Added directions to install gimp to the answer.

Comment: It seems you have a lot of broken ppa in your sources list. Did you upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04? Then you may need to upgrade or remove your outdated ppa as well. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them

Comment: @ Takkat how do I know which version I have? As I said, someone else installed it for me... I usually update everything the update manager prompts me, isn't that enough? thanks

Comment: @Ana: at the top panel right side click on the "wheel", then *System Settings...* first entry. In opened window go to the bottom line in *System* and double click on *Details* - the window that opens will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

First - let's deal with the error in sources.list.d

Do Alt+F2 and run this command

```
gksudo nautilus /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

You will be asked for password - this is your password.

The file manager will open in the correct location, look for

> matthaeus123-mrw-gimp-svn-oneiric.list.save.1

right click on it and delete it.

Any files in that directory should either end with

list or save - nothing else.

Now do

Ctrl+Alt+T this should open a terminal - run this command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This should update apt, if you get more errors please add them to the question.

Once that has done, run this and post errors if you get any.

```
gimp
```

You can install gimp from the terminal with

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

or search for gimp in the Ubuntu Software Center and install it from there.

Comment: We should **not advice unexperienced users to run Nautilus as root.** One bad mouse movement could make the whole system unusuable.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu on a Mac - ALT+F2 seems to do nothing here... what should I open to run the command? Thank you

Comment: @ Ana use ctrl+alt+t and run it from a terminal

Comment: @ Takkat - so how would deal with removing a root owned file? You'll notice that the command to open nautilus as root would in fact open it in the correct directory. People have to learn.

Comment: Open the file directly with vi or gedit from command line. Opening nautilus first might have the user continue using nautilus as root since it opens a browser window and it is kept open after editing the file that needs editing. Even a `sudo rm /dir/to/file` is better ;)

Comment: @ forestpiskie I have inserted A LOT into my original question :) - maybe we're getting closer to fixing it? thanks for being so helpful